# Error Calling Unmanaged DLL Function from Managed Code

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I've written a DLL in unmanaged visual C++, and I'm having a little trouble getting it to work with both C# and C++ applications.  Here's what the prototype in the C++ DLL looks like:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int WINAPI ZBNConnect( UCHAR dev, LPARAM hWnd, ZBCallbackFn rfn, ZBCallbackFn nfn, int DevType, byte * DevAddr, ZBCallbackFn dfn );
```

My C# application can link to the function, no problem, but when it tries to call the function an exception is thrown:

```
catch (Exception e) { /* ... */ }
```

e.Message = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Oddly, if I take `WINAPI` out of the prototype in the DLL, and recompile, the C# application calls the function without any problems.  Unfortunately, the `WINAPI` must remain because that is how the function is defined in the C++ application.

The function is currently prototyped in the C# application like this:

```
public delegate int ZBNConnectDelegate(uint dev, IntPtr hWnd, USBCallbackDelegate rfn, NotifyCallbackDelegate nfn, uint DevType, byte[] DevAddr, ZBdebugCallbackDelegate dfn);
public ZBNConnectDelegate ZBNConnect;

procName = "ZBNConnect";
fUintPtr = Kernel32.GetProcAddress(dllHandle, procName);

if (fUintPtr == UIntPtr.Zero)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(procName);
}

fIntPtr = unchecked((IntPtr)(long)(ulong)fUintPtr);
ZBNConnect = (ZBNConnectDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(fIntPtr, typeof(ZBNConnectDelegate));
```

How can I modify the C# application to get this working?  Thanks.

**EDIT: Additional Information**

A static link (`[DllImport...]`) is not an option because depending on which hardware is attached to the system a different DLL that supports the attached hardware is loaded at run-time.  Both DLLs have the same API calls.

Comment: this isn't DLL hell that's entirely different

Comment: Did you try to put extern in the prototype ?

Comment: So, how do you initialize `ZBNConnect` and make it point to the unmanaged function? As written, it'll be `null`. And why don't you just use P/Invoke (`[DllImport] static extern`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that adding `WINAPI` to the function declaration and definition was causing the function name in the DLL to be mangled.  Unfortunately, `WINAPI` was required to maintain compatibility with applications already deployed.  The fix was to add an extra export to the linker:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:ZBNConnect=_ZBNConnect@28")
```

Answer (score 3):

Something is basically wrong.  You declared a delegate, as though the function is a callback.  Doesn't look like a callback at all, it look like something you should declare with [DllImport].  To make it work like you did, you'd have to pinvoke LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress().  What [DllImport] does under the hood.  I don't see you using that.

Comment: Okay, so you actually do use GetProcAddress.  Well, the unmanaged code is taking a nose dive on a null pointer.  There are a large number of candidates, the function arguments are all pointers.  You'll have to debug it.  I think you already know how to debug unmanaged code, right?

Comment: I haven't tried stepping into the DLL, but when I step through the managed code `fIntPtr` and `ZBNConnect` are assigned values (not NULL).

Comment: You cannot step into unmanaged code, you have to set a breakpoint on the function.

Answer (score 0):

The `WINAPI` macro changes the calling convention.

Try

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall]
public delegate Int32 ZBNConnectDelegate(Byte dev, IntPtr hWnd, USBCallbackDelegate rfn, NotifyCallbackDelegate nfn, Int32 DevType, Byte[] DevAddr, ZBdebugCallbackDelegate dfn);
```

Answer (score 0):

`extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int WINAPI ZBNConnect( UCHAR dev, LPARAM hWnd, ZBCallbackFn rfn, ZBCallbackFn nfn, int DevType, byte * DevAddr, ZBCallbackFn dfn );`

`public delegate int ZBNConnectDelegate(uint dev, IntPtr hWnd, USBCallbackDelegate rfn, NotifyCallbackDelegate nfn, uint DevType, byte[] DevAddr, ZBdebugCallbackDelegate dfn);`

C++ UCHARs (dev) are 1-byte values and C# uint's are 4. You're trashing the stack when you make the native call, and for some reason, WINAPI is letting you get away with it. Also, using the delegate like this instead of doing the normal P/Invoke DllImport is most likely going to cause you problems since you can't customize how things are marshaled.

Comment: Pass-by-value arguments smaller than a machine word get widened when placed on the stack.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure I believe that you're 100% guaranteed to get away with it, though it does explain why WINAPI works. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

If you can detect the correct DLL at runtime from the C# side, I would use two DllImport declaractions:

```
[DllImport("Dll1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "ZBNConnect")]
extern static int ZBNConnect1(...)
[DllImport("Dll2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "ZBNConnect")]
extern static int ZBNConnect2(...)

public static int ZBNConnect(...)
{
    if (UseDll1)
        return ZBNConnect1(...);
   return ZBNConnect2(...);
}
```

**Note**

P/Invoke is handed by dynamic loading. If you never call ZBNConnect1, Dll1.dll is never loaded and visa versa.

**Updated**

Added EntryPoint= to DllImport.